# Hiding DIV when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I developed a PHP form which auto submits data and shows data using mySQL queries. I have a div which I require to hide upon auto submit of the form. Since the page is refreshing, the jQuery of the hide is being lost.

**Form Code:**

```
<div id="map"><iframe src="url oof source" width="700" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe></div><br />

<div>

<div class="dropdown">
<span style="color:#131787; font-size:2em; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;;">some text</span>
</div>

<div >
<form method="get" action="<?php echo $url = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
<select name="country" onchange='this.form.submit()'> 
    <?php $result= mysql_query('Query'); ?> 
<option value="x" selected>Select your destination</option>
    <?php while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?> 
        <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['country']);?>" > 
            <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['country']); ?> 
        </option> 
    <?php } ?> 
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" /><br /><br/>
</select>
</form>
</div>

</div>
```

Upon Auto submit, it captures the choice in a variable and displays data.

Example of some data which is displayed upon submit:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["action"])) { 
    $var1= $wpdb->get_results("Query");
    $var2= $wpdb->get_results("Query");
    $var3= $wpdb->get_results("Query");
    $var4= $wpdb->get_results("Query");


if (empty($var1))
    { echo '<h3 style="color:red;">No Results</h3>';} 
else 
    {foreach ( $var11 as $var1 ) {
        foreach ( $var22 as $var2 ){
}}}

?>
```

The script I am trying to use to hide the div is the below:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() { $('#map').hide(); }</script>
```

The hiding is not happening upon refresh. Could you kindly help me out in this guys please.

Comment: @HeroFTime it is in the first line of code in the first area of code I am supplying.

Comment: Presumably you're loading jQuery in your document? How do you determine whether to run this script? None of this is shown in your post.

Comment: You have not closed the document ready function? Try adding a ) after the last } before the </script tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could just add it to `isset($_GET['action'])` condition, like:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["action"])) {
    $var1 = $wpdb - > get_results("Query");
    $var2 = $wpdb - > get_results("Query");
    $var3 = $wpdb - > get_results("Query");
    $var4 = $wpdb - > get_results("Query");


    if (empty($var1)) {
        echo '<h3 style="color:red;">No Results</h3>';
    } else {
        foreach($var11 as $var1) {
            foreach($var22 as $var2) {
            }
        }
    }
    echo '<script>$(document).ready(function() { $(\'#map\').hide(); });</script>';
}
?>
```

But also, this might be better:

```
<?php
$display = "block";
if (isset($_GET["action"])) {
    $var1 = $wpdb - > get_results("Query");
    $var2 = $wpdb - > get_results("Query");
    $var3 = $wpdb - > get_results("Query");
    $var4 = $wpdb - > get_results("Query");

    if (empty($var1)) {
        echo '<h3 style="color:red;">No Results</h3>';
    } else {
        foreach($var11 as $var1) {
            foreach($var22 as $var2) {
            }
        }
    }
    $display = "none";
}
?>
```

And then when you show the div, you could use:

```
<div id="map" style="display: <?php echo $display; ?>">...</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted for 2nd option. But 1st option is not correct because we can't ensure this output is in the correct place of html

Comment: @DKasiponvic I implemented your above suggestion, but for some reason this is still not working and hiding the div

Comment: Which one did you try? If it is the first, then you should make sure that it is after the jquery import. Second should work anyway, and is better to use it anyway, so try it.

Comment: Managed to get it working playing around with some script positions. Many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

there's an error here:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() { $('#map').hide(); **}**</script>
```

the code should be:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() { $('#map').hide(); **});**</script>
```

Comment: I have implemented the above change but again, upon refresh this is not making the div hide.

Comment: Could i have the URL of that page?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do it like this ?

```
 <?php
if(isset($_GET["action"])) { 
$var1= $wpdb->get_results("Query");
$var2= $wpdb->get_results("Query");
$var3= $wpdb->get_results("Query");
$var4= $wpdb->get_results("Query");
$vis="display:none;";


if (empty($var1))
{ echo '<h3 style="color:red;">No Results</h3>';} 
else 
{foreach ( $var11 as $var1 ) {
    foreach ( $var22 as $var2 ){
}}}else
{
  $vis="";
}
```

?>

the html
the div you want to hide

`<div style="<?php echo $vis; ?>" >
</div>`

Or you might do it like this :
`<?php`
    `if(isset($_GET["action"])) { 
        $var1= $wpdb->get_results("Query");
        $var2= $wpdb->get_results("Query");
        $var3= $wpdb->get_results("Query");
        $var4= $wpdb->get_results("Query");`

```
if (empty($var1))
    { echo '<h3 style="color:red;">No Results</h3>';} 
else 
    {foreach ( $var11 as $var1 ) {
        foreach ( $var22 as $var2 ){
}}}else
```

{

```
?>
```

```
<div>

<div class="dropdown">
<span style="color:#131787; font-size:2em; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;;">some text</span>
</div>

<div >
<form method="get" action="<?php echo $url = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
<select name="country" onchange='this.form.submit()'> 
    <?php $result= mysql_query('Query'); ?> 
<option value="x" selected>Select your destination</option>
    <?php while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?> 
        <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['country']);?>" > 
            <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['country']); ?> 
        </option> 
    <?php } ?> 
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" /><br /><br/>
</select>
</form>
</div>

</div>
 <?php } ?>
```

This result's in not even needing javascript for it when using php.

Comment: I implemented the first solution but your code isn't correct u cannot have two else after each other in PHP unless using elseif